# I/O hasNextLine() - skip every other line when checking for blank line in java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I want to read multiple matrices separated by a blank line from a text file. I am going step by step. For now as part of a testing,i just want to display the matrices to the console by adding the "Blank" word between each matrix.
when I run the code below, only every other lines are displayed? how is a blank line recognized? what is actually happening?

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        //check for blank line
        if (scan.nextLine().trim().length()==0){
            System.out.println("BLANK"); 
        }else {
          System.out.println(scan.nextLine()); 

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `nextLine` twice for each time that the line is not blank.

Read the line once and keep it in a variable

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    //check for blank line
    String val = scan.nextLine();
    if (val.trim().length()==0){
        System.out.println("BLANK"); 
    }else {
      System.out.println(val); 

    }
  }
```

Comment: i see... it makes sense!